# Customize Wikitude main view with Wikitude API

Tags: android, wikitude

I'm trying to use Wikitude API in an Android app, but there's very little documentation about it.

So, is there any way to add an action bar to the wikitude view? And some buttons? Because I just see the way to add menu buttons, but nothing else.

Comment: Have you found any info on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I asked in the developers site http://www.wikitude.com/en/developers but I didn't get feedback (you can see my questions at the bottom). Maybe you could also ask there. It's a pity that this API is so poorly documented. If you find out anything, please let me know.

Comment: I got an answer from them, but they gave me the code for iPhone, if you need it let me know

Answer (score 0):

IF you read the document we can just customise things which are given in doc like adding menu buttons and appending images to poi. As I asked to developer of wikitude they replied me as, when I asked about customising UI.

-Unfortunately your feature is not possible in current SDK but upcoming ARchitect project will enable this and a huge number of other features.

Stay tuned.
http://www.wikitude.com/en/architect